# how to insert a record in the database using apache camel jpa?

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, apache-camel

I don't understand how to use camel-jpa.

I have a entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "task")
public class Task {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "task_uuid", nullable = false)
    private UUID taskUuid;

    @Column(name = "status", nullable = false)
    private String status;
}
```

and repository

```
@Repository
public interface TaskRepository extends JpaRepository<Task, Long> {
}
```

In this class, I listen to queue_1 and convert the message to a format for transmission to queue_2

```
@Service
public class RoutingMessage extends RouteBuilder {

    private final TaskRepository taskRepository;

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RoutingMessage.class);

    @Autowired
    public RoutingMessage(TaskRepository taskRepository) {
        this.taskRepository = taskRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("jms:{{queue1}}")
                .process(exchange -> {
                    String s = JsonUtil.convertJsonToXmlTaskEntity(String.valueOf(exchange.getIn().getBody()));
                    exchange.getIn().setBody(s);
                })
                .to(ExchangePattern.InOnly, "jms:{{queue2}}")
                .log("send to queue2");
    }
}
```

How do I add an insert entity(Task) to the database in the configure() method?
(I use Spring boot)

Answer (score 0):

For a single bean:

`.to("jpa:your.package.and.entity.classname")`

For a list of beans:

`.to("jpa:your.package.and.entity.classname?entityType=java.util.ArrayList")`

I don't know where you want to save, something like:

```
from("jms:{{queue1}}")
    .process(exchange -> {
        String s = JsonUtil.convertJsonToXmlTaskEntity(String.valueOf(exchange.getIn().getBody()));
        exchange.getIn().setBody(s);
    })
    .to(ExchangePattern.InOnly, "jms:{{queue2}}")
    .log("send to queue2");
    .to("jpa:your.entity.package.Task")
```

you can do much more with the JPA component, see [docs](https://camel.apache.org/jpa.html) and [Github repository](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-jpa/src/main/docs/jpa-component.adoc)